# SendInviteResult - invalid use of incomplete type 'class firebase::Future<firebase::invites::InvitesSender::SendInviteResult>'

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-invites

On C++, how to send an invite?

```
firebase::invites::InvitesSender *sender = new firebase::invites::InvitesSender(*_app);
sender->SetTitleText("Invite Friends");
sender->SetMessageText("Try my app today, and get 200 free coins!");
sender->SetCallToActionText("Download now!");
sender->SendInvite();
```

the compiler gives the error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class firebase::Future<firebase::invites::InvitesSender::SendInviteResult>'
     sender->SendInvite();
firebase_cpp_sdk\include/firebase/invites/sender.h:12:7: error: declaration of 'class firebase::Future<firebase::invites::InvitesSender::SendInviteResult>'
 class Future;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It needs the include:

```
#include <firebase/future.h>
```